# how to define secondary- & accent-color in ember-cli-materialize?

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli, materialize

i use ember 2.2 and the ember-cli-materialize component.
My problem is, that in app/styles/app.scss i can define the $primary-color, but all other values are ignored (like $accent-color or $secondary-text-color).

here is my app.scss:

```
@import 'components/color';

$primary-color-dark:   #212121;
$primary-color:        #212121; // only this line works
$primary-color-light:  #212121;
$accent-color:         #ff6f00;
$primary-text-color:   #ff6f00;
$secondary-text-color: #ff6f00;
$divider-color:        #B6B6B6;

@import 'components/variables';
@import 'materialize';
@import 'ember-cli-materialize';
```

Comment: Where do you have such variable names from? I couldn't find `accent-color` variable in materialize css, but you try to overwrite it here.

Comment: yes, that is true... i saw this in the materialize docu. It seems like they changed some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order you have things in your SASS file is correct. You can find a list of variables that are over-writable if you navigate to:

```
bower_components/materialize/sass/components/_variables.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define those variables before import of `components/color`:

```
$primary-color-dark:   #212121;
$primary-color:        #212121; // only this line works
$primary-color-light:  #212121;
$accent-color:         #ff6f00;
$primary-text-color:   #ff6f00;
$secondary-text-color: #ff6f00;
$divider-color:        #B6B6B6;

@import 'components/color';
@import 'components/variables';
@import 'materialize';
@import 'ember-cli-materialize';
```

Comment: Unless something is actually happening in 'components/color' other than setting variables, the order you're suggesting won't change anything.  Note that the docs specifically say order it the way the OP has already done: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-materialize

Comment: this dont work. I already read the docs and i had it done like they say.